# how to create a generic type for lambda middleware in go

Tags: go

I am using go in AWS lambda and looking for a generic middleware solution. I have below code:

```golang
func WsHandler(ctx context.Context, event events.APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
}

type HandlerFunc func(context.Context, events.APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error)

func LogMiddleware(next HandlerFunc) HandlerFunc {
    return HandlerFunc(func(ctx context.Context, event events.APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
        
        return next(ctx, event)
    })
}

lambda.Start(LogMiddleware(WsHandler))
```

The middleware function has a parameter `events.APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest` because the target handler `WsHandler` uses this type.

I have another handler which takes parameter `event events.APIGatewayProxyRequest` as below. It can't use this middleware since the parameter doesn't match.

```golang
GraphqlQueryMutationHandler(ctx context.Context, event events.APIGatewayProxyRequest){
...
}
```

I have tried to change the middleware handle to `interface{}`, but it doesn't work. go complains this type.

```golang
type HandlerFunc func(context.Context, interface{}) (interface{}, error)
```

Is there any way to make the middleware works for any handler type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me share the working solution I was able to replicate on my system. First, I'm going to share with you the project layout I used:

```bash
events/
  http_event.json
  sqs_event.json
hello-world/
  main.go
sqs/
  main.go
middlewares/
  middlewares.go
```

Now, let's focus on the code.

#### `middlewares/middlewares.go`

The code is as follows:

```golang
package middlewares

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
)

type Record struct {
    events.APIGatewayProxyRequest `json:",omitempty"`
    events.SQSEvent               `json:",omitempty"`
}

type Event struct {
    Records []Record `json:"records"`
}

type HandlerFunc func(ctx context.Context, event Event) (string, error)

func LogMiddleware(ctx context.Context, next HandlerFunc) HandlerFunc {
    return HandlerFunc(func(ctx context.Context, event Event) (string, error) {
        fmt.Println("log from middleware!")
        return next(ctx, event)
    })
}
```

Let's summarize the fundamental concepts:

- We define the `Event` struct that will be our generic event. It's a wrapper around the `Record` struct.
- The `Record` struct uses the struct embedding to embed all of the events that we're going to handle (e.g. `event.APIGatewayProxyRequest` and `SQSEvent`).
- We rely on this in the middleware's signature to be as much generic as we can.

#### `events/http_event.json`

```json
{
    "records": [
        {
            "body": "{\"message\": \"hello world\"}",
            "resource": "/hello",
            "path": "/hello",
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "isBase64Encoded": false,
            "queryStringParameters": {
                "foo": "bar"
            },
            "pathParameters": {
                "proxy": "/path/to/resource"
            },
            "stageVariables": {
                "baz": "qux"
            },
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
                "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
                "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
                "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
                "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
                "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
                "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
                "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
                "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
                "Host": "1234567890.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
                "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
                "User-Agent": "Custom User Agent String",
                "Via": "1.1 08f323deadbeefa7af34d5feb414ce27.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
                "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "cDehVQoZnx43VYQb9j2-nvCh-9z396Uhbp027Y2JvkCPNLmGJHqlaA==",
                "X-Forwarded-For": "127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2",
                "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
                "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
            },
            "requestContext": {
                "accountId": "123456789012",
                "resourceId": "123456",
                "stage": "prod",
                "requestId": "c6af9ac6-7b61-11e6-9a41-93e8deadbeef",
                "requestTime": "09/Apr/2015:12:34:56 +0000",
                "requestTimeEpoch": 1428582896000,
                "identity": {
                    "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
                    "accountId": null,
                    "cognitoIdentityId": null,
                    "caller": null,
                    "accessKey": null,
                    "sourceIp": "127.0.0.1",
                    "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
                    "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
                    "userArn": null,
                    "userAgent": "Custom User Agent String",
                    "user": null
                },
                "path": "/prod/hello",
                "resourcePath": "/hello",
                "httpMethod": "GET",
                "apiId": "1234567890",
                "protocol": "HTTP/1.1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here nothing relevant to say.

#### `events/sqs_event.json`

```json
{
    "records": [
        {
            "Records": [
                {
                    "messageId": "19dd0b57-b21e-4ac1-bd88-01bbb068cb78",
                    "receiptHandle": "MessageReceiptHandle",
                    "body": "My own event payload!",
                    "attributes": {
                        "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                        "SentTimestamp": "1523232000000",
                        "SenderId": "123456789012",
                        "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1523232000001"
                    },
                    "messageAttributes": {},
                    "md5OfBody": "4d1d0024b51659ad8c3725f9ba7e2471",
                    "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
                    "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:MyQueue",
                    "awsRegion": "us-east-1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The same applies here.

#### `hello-world/main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "httplambda/middlewares"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func lambdaHandler(ctx context.Context, event middlewares.Event) (string, error) {
    _ = ctx
    fmt.Println("Path:", event.Records[0].APIGatewayProxyRequest.Path)

    fmt.Println("Hi from HTTP-triggered lambda!")

    return "", nil
}

func main() {
    // start the lambda handler
    lambda.Start(middlewares.LogMiddleware(context.Background(), lambdaHandler))
}
```

Please note how we can access the info on the event.

#### `sqs/main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "httplambda/middlewares"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

func lambdaHandler(ctx context.Context, event middlewares.Event) (string, error) {
    _ = ctx
    fmt.Println("Queue name:", event.Records[0].SQSEvent.Records[0].EventSourceARN)
    fmt.Println("Hi from SQS-triggered lambda!")
    return "", nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(middlewares.LogMiddleware(context.Background(), lambdaHandler))
}
```

#### Final

There are a couple of considerations to do:

1. Before following this solution, I tried to use the type parameters without any luck. It seems that they're not allowed in the middlewares' signatures.
2. The code is oversimplified and it's not production-ready.

Let me know if this helps or if you need anything else, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all detailed demo code. The question I have is

- if the Reocrd type has same field name appear in two event, go will complains about  `struct field Body repeats json tag "body" also at apigw.go`

- why do you use an array of Records inside event? why not use Record type directly?

Comment: another issue I found is this solution doesn't work for different response type. Some lambda response multiple value like `(apiResponse, error)`, but db stream handler response only one parameter. Is there a way to make a generic response type?

Comment: About your first question, I can say that you should forecast a slice of `Record` because you could manage more than one instance of that event. For example, you can think of the `SQS` Event Handler that could handle more than one message in a single go. That's why you should forecast a slice of `Record`. Which operation are you trying to do in order to have back the `struct field Body repeats json tag "body"` error?

Comment: I am using `golangci-lint` to check linting on my code which gives me such error. I can add `//nolint:all` to get around that issue.

Comment: With `golangci-lint` version `v1.51.1` it works fine on my system. Maybe you've different configs with different checks. With the standard one, it should work. Let me know!

Comment: About the different return types question, I'd say that the easiest way is to discard the return value not relevant for that specific case. Another option could be to handle a single struct with a field dedicated to the error but it seems more contrived than the first approach.

Comment: For `Records` array type, do I have to convert all event to an array before calling the lambda?

Comment: Yeah, as mentioned before, you should convert to an array the input event because you could manage also more than a message (e.g. the `SQSEvent` handler). You can refer to the files `events/http_event.json` and `events/sqs_event.json` in the answer. If this is not clear to you, I can edit the answer by accepting only a single instance. Let me know!